# How to match anything but 'just spaces' using .Net Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a string when it contains anything but not 'only spaces'.

Spaces are fine, and can be anywhere as long as there is something else.

I can't seem to get a match when a space appears anywhere.

(EDIT: I am looking to do this in regex as I ultimately want to combine it with other regex patterns using | )

Here is my test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "123", "1 3", "12 ", "1  " , "  3", "   "};

        string r = "^[^ ]{3}$";
        foreach (string s in strings)
        {
            Match match = new Regex(r).Match(s);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("string='{0}', regex='{1}', match='{2}'", s, r, match.Value));
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
string='123', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match='123'
string='1 3', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match=''
string='12 ', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match=''
string='1  ', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match=''
string='  3', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match=''
string='   ', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match=''
```

What I want is this:

```
string='123', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match='123' << VALID
string='1 3', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match='1 3' << VALID
string='12 ', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match='12 ' << VALID
string='1  ', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match='1  ' << VALID
string='  3', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match='  3' << VALID
string='   ', regex='^[^ ]{3}$', match=''    << NOT VALID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for a regular expression here. You can use [`string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.STRING.ISNULLORWHITESPACE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

A regular expression is this:

```
[^ ]
```

What this does is simple: It checks if your string contains anything that is not a space.

I adjusted your code slightly by adding `match.Success` to the output:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "123", "1 3", "12 ", "1  " , "  3", "   ", "" };

string r = "[^ ]";
foreach (string s in strings)
{
    Match match = new Regex(r).Match(s);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("string='{0}', regex='{1}', match='{2}', " +
                                    "is match={3}", s, r, match.Value,
                                    match.Success));
}
```

The result will be:

```
string='123', regex='[^ ]', match='1', is match=True
string='1 3', regex='[^ ]', match='1', is match=True
string='12 ', regex='[^ ]', match='1', is match=True
string='1  ', regex='[^ ]', match='1', is match=True
string='  3', regex='[^ ]', match='3', is match=True
string='   ', regex='[^ ]', match='', is match=False
string='', regex='[^ ]', match='', is match=False
```

BTW: Instead of `new Regex(r).Match(s)` you should use `Regex.Match(s, r)`. This allows the regex engine to cache the pattern.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I would like to use regex here if possible as I'm using regex for some other validation, not just the spaces issue.

Comment: @errolc: Do you really need the value of the string as part of `match.Value`? Or is all you are interested in that `match.Success` is `true`?

Comment: I just want to know if it matches. I don't care what the value is. I'm using it validate a string. Either its valid according to the regex 'validator'....in which case yay, continue or..... it isnt, barf and exit.

Comment: In that case, the simple expression from my answer is all you need. It will only match if there is a character other than a space anywhere in your string

Comment: So for this case. A string with something in it would be valid but a blank string would not be.

Comment: Spaces are allowed though. Its just 'all spaces' that is not. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @errolc: Please see my updated answer. It will match as long as there is at least one character other than a space in the string. If that's the case, it doesn't matter how many spaces there are.

Comment: Got it. I understand now. Thanks a lot for your help and the tip about using Regex.Match().

Answer (score 7):

I'd use

```
^\s*\S+.*?$
```

Breaking down the regex...

- `^` - start of line
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace characters
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace characters
- `.*?` - any characters (whitespace or not - non-greedy -> match as few as possible)
- `$` - end of line.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @Grhm! It doesn't seem to allow the new-line character `\n`, should `\n*` be placed immediately after `^`?

Comment: @Ian Campbell you probably need to add a SingleLine option to make the . character march newlines. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about using `^\s+$` and simply negating the result of `Match()`?

Comment: `IsMatch()` can also be used.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Time for me to look more closely at the Regex class.